# Running into "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags.zip([Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/micrometer/core/instrument/Tags;"

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I working on a SpringBoot(2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) application.

When I run a test for my Entities with the following annotations, I have a successful run of my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
```

However, when I run a test for my Service layer with the following annotations, I'm getting an Exception that started appearing all of a sudden:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags.zip([Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/micrometer/core/instrument/Tags;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags.zip([Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/micrometer/core/instrument/Tags;
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsConfiguration.bindDataSourceToRegistry(DataSourcePoolMetricsConfiguration.java:71)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsConfiguration.bindDataSourcesToRegistry(DataSourcePoolMetricsConfiguration.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    ... 40 more
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.3'
    id 'idea'
    id 'maven'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'helloworld'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
            details.useVersion '5.0.2.RELEASE'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url myMavenRepoReadUrl
    }
}

ext {
    postgresqlVersion = "42.1.4"
    disruptorVersion = "3.3.6"
    springfoxSwagger2Version = "2.7.0"
    guavaVersion = "23.5-jre"
    commonsTextVersion = "1.1"
    commonsLang3Version = "3.7"
    woodstoxCoreAslVersion = "4.4.1"
    springRestDocsVersion = "2.0.0.RELEASE"
    snippetsDir = file("$buildDir/generated-snippets")
    Date buildTimeAndDate = new Date()
    buildDate = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(buildTimeAndDate)
    buildTime = new SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format(buildTimeAndDate)
}

dependencies {
    asciidoctor "org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:${springRestDocsVersion}"

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter") {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2") {
        exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j", module: "log4j-slf4j-impl"
    }
    compile("com.lmax:disruptor:${disruptorVersion}")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfoxSwagger2Version}")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springfoxSwagger2Version}")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-text:${commonsTextVersion}")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonsLang3Version}")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml")
    compile("org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:${woodstoxCoreAslVersion}")
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    runtime("com.h2database:h2")
    runtime("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}")
    runtime("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:${springRestDocsVersion}")
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.9"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("$buildDir/reports/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

asciidoctor {
    dependsOn 'test'
    inputs.dir snippetsDir

    sourceDir = file('src/main/asciidoc')
    sources {
        include 'api-guide.adoc'
    }
    outputDir = file("$buildDir/docs")
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

jar {
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    dependsOn 'asciidoctor'
    from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/docs'
    }

    manifest {
        attributes('Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                'Build-Date': buildDate,
                'Build-Time': buildTime)
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url myMavenRepoWriteUrl
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}

mainClassName = 'HelloWorldApplication'

task bootRunDev(type: BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
    group = 'Application'

    doFirst() {
        main = project.mainClassName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev'
    }
}

task bootRunTest(type: BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
    group = 'Application'

    doFirst() {
        main = project.mainClassName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'test'
    }
}
```

Here's my test for the Service Layer:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class SecurityPrivilegeServiceImplTest {
    private static SecurityPrivilege testSecurityPrivilege =
            new SecurityPrivilegeBuilder()
                    .name(PrivilegeName.TEST_PRIVILEGE_1)
                    .description("Test User Privilege")
                    .build();
    private final UUID uuidTestSecurityPrivilege = UUID.randomUUID();
    @Autowired
    private SecurityPrivilegeService securityPrivilegeService;
    @MockBean
    private SecurityPrivilegeRepository securityPrivilegeRepository;
    private SecurityPrivilege adminPrivilege;
    private SecurityPrivilege superUserPrivilege;
    private SecurityPrivilege userPrivilege;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // given
        adminPrivilege =
                new SecurityPrivilegeBuilder()
                        .name(PrivilegeName.ADMIN)
                        .description("Admin Privilege")
                        .build();

        superUserPrivilege =
                new SecurityPrivilegeBuilder()
                        .name(PrivilegeName.SUPERUSER)
                        .description("Super User Privilege")
                        .build();

        userPrivilege =
                new SecurityPrivilegeBuilder()
                        .name(PrivilegeName.USER)
                        .description("User Privilege")
                        .build();

        List<SecurityPrivilege> allSecurityPrivileges = Arrays.asList(adminPrivilege, superUserPrivilege, userPrivilege);

        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.findById(11L))
                .willReturn(Optional.ofNullable(adminPrivilege));
        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.findById(-99L))
                .willReturn(null);

        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.findByUuid(uuidTestSecurityPrivilege))
                .willReturn(Optional.ofNullable(testSecurityPrivilege));

        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.findByName(adminPrivilege.getName()))
                .willReturn(Optional.ofNullable(adminPrivilege));

        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.findAll())
                .willReturn(allSecurityPrivileges);

        given(securityPrivilegeRepository.saveAndFlush(testSecurityPrivilege))
                .willReturn(testSecurityPrivilege);
    }

    /************************************************************************************************************
     * Test the Finders
     ************************************************************************************************************/
    @Test
    public void whenGoodUuid_thenRetrieveSecurityPrivilege() {
        Optional<SecurityPrivilege> found = securityPrivilegeService.findByUuid(uuidTestSecurityPrivilege);
        verifyFindByUuidIsCalledOnce(uuidTestSecurityPrivilege);
        assert found.isPresent();
        assertThat(uuidTestSecurityPrivilege.equals(found.get().getUuid()));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenBadUuid_thenRetrieveSecurityPrivilege() {
        UUID randomUuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        Optional<SecurityPrivilege> found = securityPrivilegeService.findByUuid(randomUuid);
        verifyFindByUuidIsCalledOnce(randomUuid);
        assertThat(found == null);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void whenNullPrivilegeName_thenIllegalArgumentExceptionIsRaised() {
        securityPrivilegeService.findByName(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenGoodSecurityPrivilegeName_thenRetrieveSecurityPrivilege() {
        Optional<SecurityPrivilege> found = securityPrivilegeService.findByName(adminPrivilege.getName().name());
        verifyGetSecurityPrivilegeBySecurityPrivilegeNameIsCalledOnce(adminPrivilege.getName().name());
        assertThat(found.get().getName().name()).isEqualTo(adminPrivilege.getName().name());
    }

    @Test
    public void given3SecurityPrivilege_whenGetAll_thenReturn3Records() {
        List<SecurityPrivilege> allSecurityPrivileges = securityPrivilegeService.findAll();
        verifyFindAllSecurityPrivilegesIsCalledOnce();
        assertThat(allSecurityPrivileges).hasSize(3)
                .extracting(SecurityPrivilege::getName)
                .contains(
                        PrivilegeName.ADMIN,
                        PrivilegeName.SUPERUSER,
                        PrivilegeName.USER);
    }

    /************************************************************************************************************
     * Test the Create
     ************************************************************************************************************/

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void whenNullUser_thenIllegalArgumentExceptionIsRaised() {
        securityPrivilegeService.save(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenValidUser_thenUserShouldBeSaved() {
        SecurityPrivilege savedSecurityPrivilege = securityPrivilegeService.save(testSecurityPrivilege);
        verifySaveAndFlushIsCalledOnce();
        assertThat(StringUtils.equals(testSecurityPrivilege.getName().name(), savedSecurityPrivilege.getName().name()));
        assertThat(StringUtils.equals(testSecurityPrivilege.getDescription(), savedSecurityPrivilege.getDescription()));
    }

    /************************************************************************************************************
     * Test the Delete
     ************************************************************************************************************/

    @Test
    public void whenValidPrivilegeName_thenSecurityPrivilegeShouldBeDeleted() {
        boolean deletedSuccessfully = securityPrivilegeService.deleteByName(adminPrivilege.getName().name());
        verifyDeletePrivilegeNameIsCalledOnce(adminPrivilege.getName().name());
        assertThat(deletedSuccessfully);
    }

    /************************************************************************************************************
     * Helpers for Verification
     ************************************************************************************************************/

    private void verifyFindByUuidIsCalledOnce(UUID uuid) {
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1))
                .findByUuid(uuid);
        Mockito.reset(securityPrivilegeRepository);
    }

    private void verifyGetSecurityPrivilegeBySecurityPrivilegeNameIsCalledOnce(String privilegeName) {
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1))
                .findByName(PrivilegeName.valueOf(privilegeName));
        Mockito.reset(securityPrivilegeRepository);
    }

    private void verifyFindAllSecurityPrivilegesIsCalledOnce() {
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).findAll();
        Mockito.reset(securityPrivilegeRepository);
    }

    private void verifySaveAndFlushIsCalledOnce() {
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1))
                .saveAndFlush(any(SecurityPrivilege.class));
        Mockito.reset(securityPrivilegeRepository);
    }

    private void verifyDeletePrivilegeNameIsCalledOnce(String privilegeName) {
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1))
                .findByName(PrivilegeName.valueOf(privilegeName));
        Mockito.verify(securityPrivilegeRepository, VerificationModeFactory.times(1))
                .delete(any(SecurityPrivilege.class));
        Mockito.reset(securityPrivilegeRepository);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class SecuritySecurityPrivilegeServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SecurityPrivilegeService securityPrivilegeService() {
            return new SecurityPrivilegeServiceImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

My application.yml

```
app:
    contextPath: /api
    hostName: localhost
    name: HelloWorld
    port: 9876
logging:
    level:
        org:
            hibernate:
                SQL: debug
            springframework: info
        net:
            helloworld:
                security:
                    web:  debug
server:
    port: 9876
    servlet:
        context-path: /api
spring:
    application:
        admin:
            enabled: false
            jmx-name: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=HelloWorld
        name: HelloWorld
    datasource:
      initialization-mode: always
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
    http:
        converters:
            preferred-json-mapper: jackson
    jackson:
        deserialization:
            fail-on-unknown-properties: true
        serialization:
            indent-output: true
    jpa:
        open-in-view: true
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: validate
        properties:
            hibernate:
                jdbc:
                    time_zone: GMT+8
```

Comment: What does your tests actually look like? not enough data

Comment: Thanks @MikeTung, included the test in the end.

Comment: `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` I don't think you need this. How is your application properties configured?

Comment: Added my application.yml

Comment: BTW, this was working until a couple days ago. Don't know what changed with the dependencies all of a sudden.

Comment: Removing the `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` has no impact.

Comment: maybe your dependency is broken. Try to delete the dependencies from your local and import it again (with the --refresh-dependencies flag, or just delete the dependencies from wherever gradle saves them, usually under "module-2" inside the ".gradle" folder)

Comment: Thanks @GuySmorodinsky - That was it, I just had to execute `gw clean build --refresh-dependencies`. You guys saved me a lot of agony.

Comment: Hi @GuySmorodinsky - Please answer the question so that I can vote for your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your dependency is broken. Try to delete the dependencies from your local and import it again (build your project with the `--refresh-dependencies` flag)

Comment: The option `--refresh-dependencies` does not exist, at least in Maven 3.6.3